# GitHub actions using Node.JS and .NET in same job

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, github-actions

I'm making a JavaScript API for a .NET project. So I need GitHub actions to have both Node.JS and .NET Core (2.1, 2.2, 3.0 or 3.1) installed. Is this possible?

This is my GitHub actions config YAML file:

```yaml
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build
    - run: npm test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, you can have multiple matrix arguments:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x]
        dotnet: [ '2.1.811', '2.2.103', '3.0', '3.1.x' ]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: Setup dotnet
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet }}
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build
    - run: npm test
    - run: dotnet build <my project>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to have multiple `with` arguments. `with: dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet }} node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}`